# How to query data from dynamoDB table with multiple filter layers?

Tags: amazon-web-services, if-statement, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I'm using AWS appsync API with lambda resolver. My question is how to add 2 separate filter when querying data from DynamoDB using direct lambda resolver?

**For Example :**

My app is a news app. It has a feed. I want to show content in that feed like below:

Mixture of: News of native country + News with 100K+ views. My problem is if I add `and` operator, condition will be like: **native country news `AND` news with 100k+ views** it will filter out only native country new with 100K+ views. But I want to show both native country news as well as global news with 100k+ views. Secondly if I use `OR` operator then if one condition become true it will fetch that type of content.

**Is there any way to add multiple layers of filter to a dynamoDB query?**